# Ruby remote partial being rendered twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

I've spent this afternoon moving code around, trying different things, etc but am unable to solve my (probably simple) problem. I have a button on my index layout that displays a partial form in a modal dialogue to a) create new entries or b) edit existing ones. I'm using the materialize, simple form and client side validation gems.

When I click the button for a new entry the modal appears twice, which looks a bit rubbish but more importantly when I try to save an entry two POST requests are made.

Obviously, I just want the form partial to be rendered once... but I can't work out why its happening twice.

Thanks all for your help, let me know if you need any more than what I have provided below.

---

This is the button code in the **index.html.erb** layout

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn">

    <%= link_to "<i class='material-icons'>add</i>".html_safe, 
    new_patient_path, :remote => true, :id => 'new_patient_link', 
    :class => "btn-floating btn-large red" %>

</div>
```

Which then loads the javascript in **new.js.erb**

```
$('#modal_partial').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>');
```

That subsequently renders the **_form.html.erb** partial into the following div (which is stored in a **shared/_footer.html.erb** partial and sits at the bottom of the index page.

```
<div id="form_modal_wrap">
  <div id="modal_partial" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the **_form.html.erb** partial:

```
<div id="edit_patient_modal" class="";>
<%= simple_form_for @patient, validate: true, remote: true do |f| %>

  <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 0px;">

    <h4 class="col s12" style="margin: 0px; padding: 10px 25px;">New Patient</h4>


    <%= f.error_notification %>


    <div class="row">

      <div class="col s12" style="padding: 0px;">

        <ul class="tabs" style="padding: 0px;">

          <li class="tab col"><a class="active"  href="#demographics">Demographics</a></li>
          <li class="tab col"><a class="active"  href="#admission">Admission</a></li>
          <li class="tab col"><a href="#presentation">Presentation</a></li>
          <li class="tab col"><a href="#jobs">Jobs</a></li>
          <li class="tab col"><a href="#results">Results</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>


      <div id="demographics" class="col s12" style="padding: 20px;">

        <%= f.input :nhs, :label => "NHS"  %>

        <%= f.input :fname, :label => "Firstname" %>
        <%= f.input :lname, :label => "Lastname", validate: { presence: true, uniqueness: false }  %>
        <%= f.input :dob, :label => "DOB", as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 110,
                          end_year: Date.today.year - 12,
                          order: [:day, :month, :year] %>

        <%= f.input :mrn, :label => "MRN" %>



      </div>

      <div id="admission" class="col s12" style="padding:20px;" >

        <%= f.association :location %>
        <%= f.input :bed, :label => "Bed" %>
        <%= f.association :team, input_html: { multiple: true } %>

      </div>

      <div id="presentation" class="col s12" style="padding:20px;">



        <%= f.input :dx, :label => "Dx" %>
        <%= f.input :pmh, :label => "PMH" %>


      </div>

      <div id="jobs" class="col s12" style="padding:20px">

        <p>This job list is shared between all teams.</p>
        <%= f.input :jobs, :label => "Jobs" %>

      </div>

      <div id="results" class="col s12" style="padding:20px;">


      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Group</th>
          <th>Result</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        <% @patient.results.each do |result| %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= Investigation.find(result.investigation_id).group %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= Investigation.find(result.investigation_id).short %>
              <%= result.value %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= result.date %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
      </div>

    </div>



  </div>


  <div class="modal-footer"> 

    <a id="modal_close" href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-pink btn-flat">Cancel</a>
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => "waves-effect btn" %>

  </div>



<% end -%>
```

The following javascript is in the bottom of the **_form.html.erb** partial:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal_partial .tabs').tabs();
    $('#modal_partial select').formSelect();
    $('#modal_partial').modal();
    $('#modal_partial').modal('open');
    $('form').enableClientSideValidations(); 
  });

  $("#modal_close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modal_partial').modal('close');
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I worked out what I'd done in the end...

in **application.js** I had added both of the following:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
```

By removing either one of these the modals only appeared once. After reading the documentation I only need rails-ujs as it performs the same functions as jquery_ujs, but without having a dependency upon jquery. It does not mean that you can't still have jquery as an independent requirement (as I still do).

So the solution was to **delete the line //= require jquery-ujs** and just have the following:

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

Thanks lacostenycoder for you help

Comment: There was no way for us to know this since you did not post the JS requires

Comment: Yes absolutely, my apologies. I thought I would post the answer anyway in case someone else had made the same silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to debug this is to check EVERY part of your code which loads javascript including your layouts.  Something is causing the form to duplicate, but it's impossible to debug without seeing all of the code.

Comment: I'm rendering it within the partial because I was finding that the tabs and select elements of materialize wouldn't be applied to a partial rendered after the main page.

If I remove that line from the javascript I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined. If I remove the subsequent line with .modal('open') then no modal is displayed but I don't get an error.

Comment: As the javascript is within the partial, it fires once the partial is ready rather than the initial index page (the partial is only loaded on a click of a button). Moving the divs still results in the partial being loaded twice, just lose the materialize modal design as those classes are required for the modal to work. (https://materializecss.com/modals.html). Tricky!